Are photons both waves and particles, or particles subject to a probability wave?
We know that photons exhibit wave-like behavior, as demonstrated in the double-slit experiment. As the force carriers for electromagnetic interactions, photons are also particles. Does a photon's probability wave couple with its electromagnetic dynamics to give rise to its wave-like nature, or are photons something more unique?

This question is similar to: What is the relation between electromagnetic wave and photon?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Indeed, see my answers at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/438946/186017.

And mine at How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?

IMO this is the easiest way to understand it. Real photon is a wave in the EM field, not a particle, only because the wave is small it is like a particle. Virtual photons are the force carriers, these are completely imaginary and used as a placeholder by physics. Real photon is the energy carrier in the EM field.  The EM field guides the probability distribution (modes) in any apparatus. The EM field sees all the electrons in the apparatus, it structures the probability paths per Feynman. In the DSE no photons in the dark bands all photons go to the light bands.
